# Expand Fancybox width to match an <embed> PDF

Tags: jquery, html, embed, fancybox

I've got a [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) (2) whose content is an `<embed src='some_pdf.pdf'/>`, i.e.

```
var embed = $("<embed></embed>"),
    pdf_url = "http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/Zombies.pdf";

embed.attr('src', pdf_url);

$.fancybox.open(embed);
```

Here it is [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/PTP6v/).

I'd like the Fancybox to automatically resize the width to the size of the PDF (which, I should note, may vary because the PDF contains landscape or portrait pages), and about 90% the height of the window.

Unfortunately the best I've come up with so far is a hard-coded width, and setting the embed height, i.e.

```
embed.attr('width', '900');
embed.attr('height', parseInt($(window).height() * 0.9, 10));
```

I'd be grateful for any thoughts on how one might resize a Fancybox to the size of a PDF included with `<embed>`.

I'm using Chrome 15, and ideally I'd like a solution that works across recent versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: hmm didn't know you could properly embed PDFs... have you tested this in all browsers?

Comment: @Jakub: it works in the browsers we're using. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Fancybox is unable to calculate the size of the coming content (most likely will happen with object elements) then it uses its `minWidth` and `minHeight` default settings.

Try passing the right `<embed>` tag attributes like:

```
var embed = $("<embed></embed>"),
pdf_url = "http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/Zombies.pdf";

embed.attr('src', pdf_url);
embed.attr('width', '100%');
embed.attr('height', '100%');
embed.attr('type', 'application/pdf');
```

and tell fancybox not to use its `autoSize` settings so it will take the values coming from the `<embed>` `width` and `height` attributes like:

```
$.fancybox.open(embed,{
autoSize: false
});
```

That will do the trick and will resize the PDF viewer to the viewport.

**NOTE**: If you are using HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I would recommend you to set the height just to 99% like:

```
embed.attr('height', '99%');
```

to avoid a double vertical scroll bar in your PDF viewer. This is because the way HTML5 initializes margins.

Comment: Please, how would this very issue be approached in Fancybox 3? Thanks.